# How do I get shadow achievements in Cookie Clicker?

Tags: achievements, cookie-clicker

I have two of them, those being Speed Baking I and God Complex, but what are the other ones and how do I get them?

Comment: Have you looked into the [wiki](https://cookieclicker.fandom.com/wiki/Achievement#Shadow_Achievements)?

Comment: I'm on a school computer and I can't get onto wiki :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The others are:

- **Cheated cookies taste awful:** Hack in some cookies.
- **Hardcore:** Get to 1,000,000,000 cookies baked with no upgrades purchased.
- **Speed baking II:** Get to 1,000,000 cookies baked in less than 25 minutes played time.
- **Speed baking III:** Get to 1,000,000 cookies baked in less than 15 minutes played time.
- **True Neverclick:** Make your first 1,000,000 cookies without any big-cookie clicks.
- **Just plain lucky:** You have 1 chance in 500,000 every second of earning this achievement.
- **Four-leaf cookie:** Have 4 golden cookies on the screen simultaneously.
- **Third-party:** Use an add-on.
- **When the cookies ascend just right:** Ascend with exactly 1 trillion cookies.
- **Last Chance to See:** Burst a shiny wrinkler.
- **So much to do so much to see:** Manage a cookie legacy for at least a year.
- **Gaseous assets:** Have your stock market profits surpass a whole year of CpS ($31,536,000).
- **Seven horseshoes:** Click 27,777 golden cookies.
- **All-natural cane sugar:** Harvest a golden sugar lump.
- **Endless cycle:** Ascend 1,000 times.